# Intrinsic Curvature of a T-Shirt

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry

My Family and I had an Argument about sewing, because I was wondering where the curvature, in a T-Shirt at the shoulder, comes from.

As far as I know all sewing patterns are flat and therefor these things have zero curvature!

But a shoulder part of a T-Shirt has a positive intrinsic curvature, but I thought that continuous transformations  can’t change the intrinsic curvature!

Please explain it to me, because I can’t (I have a small self-thought math base and I know almost nothing about sewing).
Thank you!

Comment: **Intrinsic** means it is a property of the surface, not the embedding. You might study Gauss's Theorema Egregium first? Curvature can change.

Answer (score 1):

Fabric stretches. If you made a T-shirt out of paper it would break or crumple if you tried to force it to fit smoothly over your shoulders.

Continuous transformations don't necessarily preserve curvature. E.g., look at the graph of $(x, y) \mapsto x^2 + y^2$ in $\Bbb{R}^3$. Isometries do preserve curvature, but the mapping from the flat T-shirt to the T-shirt after you've put it on is not an isometry.

Answer (score 0):

Transformations need to be more rigid to preserve curvature. The classic example is the continuous function from the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ to the infinitely long cylinder, where we "wrap" the plane around (think of a pirate wrapping a map into a cylinder for storage).

Comment: Cylinders are flat, but shoulders aren't.